# Visual Studio slows when saving changes to project in Windows Forms app but fast in Windows Forms app (.NET framework)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Experiencing Visual Studio slowing when saving Windows Forms app projects immediately after updating the UI, for example adding button to the UI. At the moment I hit <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>, it takes up to a minute before saving!

Please what should I do?

I tried testing by creating a similar project in Windows Forms app (.NET framework). I discovered that for the .NET framework, it takes only a few seconds to save but Windows Forms app takes too long to save.

Comment: The two types of projects use different WinForms designer (new for .NET Core, and old for .NET Framework), so the performance difference is expected. Report to Microsoft and wait for fixes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: Have done that, they hardly respond. The .designer is slow saving changes

Comment: It is not slow, it is your machine that made it slow.  The  .NETCore designer runs out-of-process, that makes it vulnerable to aggressive anti-malware.  Disable it and try again.

Comment: Please refer to [Visual Studio Designer loading time is too long](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-designer-loading-time-is-too-long/1590350). You need to upgrade Visual Studio to the latest version

Comment: I have upgraded, still not fast saving changes, but fast when saving. NET project

Comment: @AtsenoguaSandra Which .net version is the target framework of your project?